# Multifield in magnolia

Tags: classcastexception, multivalue, magnolia

I want to make a multifield in magnolia. See my configuration below

[image]
But when I open my dialog, it is empty and doesn't contain any fields except the buttons and in the tomcat log I see the following errors:

> Can't set property [transformerClass] to value
>   [info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.multi.MultiValueSubChildrenNodePropertiesTransformer]
>   in bean
>   [info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.MultiValueFieldDefinition] for
>   node /modules/templating-jsp/dialogs/singleLink/form/tabs/events due
>   to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke
>   info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.ConfiguredFieldDefinition.setTransformerClass
>   on bean class 'class
>   info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.MultiValueFieldDefinition' -
>   java.lang.ClassCastException@5d01b367 - had objects of type
>   "java.lang.String" but expected signature "java.lang.Class"

Could you please help me with this error and explain what is wrong with my configuration?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho you are setting it all one level too high. You have defined tab "events", under "events" you should have subnode "fields", then under that, another subnode "events" and only under that you should be defining your properties. ... might be good idea to rename that top "events" to "eventsTab" or similar to avoid confusion.

HTH,
Jan